# Auth.net payment gateway similar to paypal

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment, authorize.net

I have below query.

We are using authorize.net payment gateway for our website. As per our internal company policy
we don't want user to enter their card details on our website, we want them to directly transfer them to authorize.net website and provide all the details(credit cardno,expiry date etc) there similar to paypal.

Does anybody have idea if this can be done. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorize.Net offers the [Simple Integration Method](http://developer.authorize.net/api/sim/) which is the equivalent of Paypal's hosted forms.